# How can I deploy my react project for production?

Tags: reactjs

How can transform my react project into script to connect it to html page?

I am a new one in react please be tolerant. My boss demands to get completed script to connect it to html page without node and etc. What shall I do? Thank you.

Comment: As the other answer has said, you could use create-react-app as it would already configure most of the things for you. But you would still need something to serve your static page, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this url: 
https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-production-deployment-part-3-heroku-316319744885

Also, Please check these steps:

1. In package.json, added this line to the scripts

```
"heroku-postbuild":
 "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run 
 build --prefix client".
```

2. Then added this 
    `"engines": { "node" : "[your node version]" }` after scripts.
3. In index.js, put the following code after your routes set up

```
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   app.use(express.static("client/build"));
   const path = require("path");
   app.get("*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", 
   "index.html"));
   });
  }
```

4. I assume that you use git for version control and already install Heroku. 
   Open your terminal, then Heroku login -> Heroku create -> git push Heroku 
   master. If you do not get any error, you are a success to deploy your app.

Hope you will get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of node, you need to first build your project. If you've initialized your project with create-react-app, run this command:

```
npm run build
```

A folder named 'build' will appear in your project root containing your production app. Now the build folder is ready to build and you can serve it with a static server like 'serve'. To install 'serve' via npm, do this:

```
npm install -g serve
```

that's it! you can serve it now:

```
serve -s build
```

You can find out more about deployment here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Answer (score 0):

by using create-react-app
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

dev: npm start or yarn start.

prod: npm run build or yarn build.